# How to avoid both deadlocks and using too many threads?

Tags: java, threadpool

Using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)` is a nice way to minimize the overhead of creating too many threads, but it may lead to a deadlock in case that all threads are waiting for another job which itself is waiting for a free thread from the pool. Sometimes the problem can be solved by using multiple thread pools, but sometimes it can't. I'm looking for something behaving similar to `newFixedThreadPool` except in case that all pooled threads are blocked - in such a case the pool should grow despite its predefined bound. *Is there something like this?*

---

Actually, the deadlock is not that important here. The real problem is "how to manage the number of *running* threads" rather than their total number. This can be also interesting when trying to keep the CPU fully utilized without creating needlessly many threads.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a contention issue, this is a *design* problem. If you want a quick fix as you described, you will only be curing the symptoms, not the underlying sickness.

You should instead refactor your design to eliminate deadlock using some other means.

Comment: A good place to start is to impose timeouts on waiting for a contested resource, so that those threads can do other things if the resource isn't being freed up. Then figure out why a(nother) thread is holding the resource for too long-- maybe it isn't being released properly in exceptional conditions, for example. Make sure you hold your resources ONLY as long as you need them, and absolutely no longer.

Comment: There's no deadlock in my design. There's just an (usually small but) unbounded number of jobs possibly waiting for another one. I really don't think changing it would improve the design.

Comment: Then maybe you shouldn't use the word "deadlock" in your question... Some people, including me, interpret "deadlock" to be the condition where there's a circular wait going on and absolutely no way to break out of it. Adding pre-emption (i.e., timeouts), limiting the amount of time the resource can be held, etc. will not only fix your problem but also prove to be a better overall design.

Comment: The deadlock is a real deadlock, but it may only happen when a *fixed thread pool* gets used, since this makes the threads themselves a contended resourse. With an unlimited number of threads there's no problem except for too many threads running. Your advice is fine, but I'm not sure if I can improve the program in this respect any further.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally a bad idea to have threads in a pool blocked waiting for other threads in the same thread pool.

I would try to change the design to a non-blocking one. If a thread needs the result of another operation that is being processed by the same executor I would have it submit a task back to the executor to run after the second operation completes. Or place an object into a queue to be picked up later when the other job finishes.

Alternatively you can do what Swing does with modal dialogs and have the thread that is about to block start up a child thread to keep processing requests until the parent thread unblocks. This is tricky to get right though and would require you to manually manage the threads which is a lot less safe than using an Executor.

Comment: +1 Switching to a non-blocking design is surely a good idea, however, it may get complicated as it sometimes means simulating threading yourself. Moreover, there are cases where the thread may be blocked in a place you don't control or maybe even don't know about. The other idea may get complicated as you wrote. Nonetheless, it's clearly the best answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

`Executor.newCachedThreadPool();`  A cached thread pool will check to see if there are any available threads.  If there is, the thread pool will re use the thread.  If it isnt, the thread pool will create a new thread.  The threads time to live is 60 seconds, so after 60 seconds the extra threads will be terminated.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not only create new threads if there is a deadlock situation but also if threads are running but a new one is submitted meanwhile. Thus if you start lots of tasks simultaneously you'll create a huge thread pool.

Comment: @Howard Yes, that's exactly my point. I'd be happy with a pool somehow limiting the number of *running* threads instead of the number of *all* threads.

Comment: @Howard Considering that every algorithm to find out if there's a deadlock (finding cycles in a large graph) will be prohibitively expensive, using some kind of easy heuristic is really the only way for that..

Comment: @Voo I was thinking about threads blocked for whatever reason, rather than deadlocked ones. You can have some thousands of tasks, so I think the cycle finding should be rather trivial. At any instant each thread may be blocked by at most a single thread.